# PostgreSQL dump and restore in different timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have two databases running on different servers in different timezones. There is a couple of tables which contains `timestamp with timezone`.

I need to dump data from one database and to import it to another with correct timestamp and correct timezone.

I use following command to dump data:

```
pg_dump -a DB_NAME > dump.sql
```

I see data are in old timestamp and timezone format: **`2013-11-29 14:30:00+02`**

Then I use command to another server to restore dump:

```
psql -d DB_NAME -f dump.sql
```

And I see that timestamps and timezone is from old server - which I think is normal.

Then I tried to put following command in the beginning of dump.sql

```
SET timezone ...
```

But still does not work. :(

This is one time operation. Once transferred data will not need sync. Is there a way to do such conversion using pg_dump and pg_restore or similar?

Answer (score 7):

The Postgres the data type [`timstamptz`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) ( = `timestamp with time zone`) stores values as UTC timestamp internally (integer value counting microseconds since 2000), which is independent of the time zone those values are *displayed* for. It does ***not*** store any time zone information like some might think, misjudging the name. You can dump and restore as much as you want.

What you ***see*** in your client depends on the [time zone setting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) of the session.

Run (in the same session to avoid artifacts):

```
SHOW timezone;
```

If you see `localtime` then Postgres uses the default setting of your server OS.

Set a different time zone (in your session with `SET timezone = ...;`, for your user or globally in the config files) to see your timestamps formatted differently. Be aware that the time zone setting in your dump file does **not** have any effect in this case, only the setting of your current session has.

Detailed explanation in this related answer:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

About the various ways to set environment variables:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Comment: `ALTER ROLE ... SET TIMEZONE=` for role importing with solved it for me